# Form Based Authentication in Wss 3.0

Tags: forms-authentication

Hey,
I need some good links references for Form Based Authentication in WSS 3.0.
and the next thing i want to know is that possible to do Form based authentication with my own database ?

thanks

SAAD TAHIR

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, [Three fantastic FBA articles on MSDN for SharePoint](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2007/12/16/Three-fantastic-FBA-articles-on-MSDN-for-SharePoint.aspx).

[More here](http://www.topsharepoint.com/form-based-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely can do FBA with your own database.  You either have to use the SQLMembershipProvider that Microsoft provides (if you don't have your own database set up yet), or you can create your own Membership Provider if you already have a database that you want to hook into.

You have to implement several functions (login, createuser, etc.) which have to know how to connect to your database.

See http://www.google.com/search?q=membershipprovider for more information.  You can do the same with the Role Provider and Profile provider if you want.

Comment: i have implemented the Fba , but when i m trying to add  Secondary site collection administrator in the site collection administrator, it gives error : "No exact match was found.". i did everything step wise bt still getting error. any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to go into the web.config and add your membership provider as one of the options in the PeoplePickerWildcards section.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136.aspx for more details (search for 'PeoplePickerWildcards')